# Outlook REST API: "The user could not be authenticated or the grant is expired." error with no apparent reason

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi

Our app is integrated with Outlook REST API, mainly for mailbox integration, and recently we are having some problems with our users suddenly unable to log in.

We use OAuth authentication with this authority `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0`

The strange thing is that when the users try to log-in I am getting this error:

> AADSTS70000: The user could not be authenticated or the grant is expired. The user must first sign in and if needed grant the client application access to the requested scope....

..however, this is not the case. The user permissions for my app are not changed, neither is his account password, etc. If the user tries to log-in in a different browser, things work just fine. Also if the user deletes the cookies in `outlook.live.com` and logs in via the new Outlook sign up instead things work fine again.

Another issue, which I believe may be related, is: sometimes the user can log in but the integration does not work any further because the API starts returning errors like:

```
{"code":"ErrorNonExistentMailbox","message":"No mailbox with such guid."}
"The operation is not supported.", etc
```

Again, no problem if the user logs in in a different browser.

I tried to work around this by forcing the user to sign out, but I can't make him delete his browser cache, of course. Any help will be very appreciated I'm running out of solutions here.